# how Oauth 2 subsequent request are secured?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am novice to how oauth2 with JWT works But must to learn it in short time :) After reading bit I draw a conclusion abstract of its work as this.

[image]

now I have two question in my mind.

(1) Is my way of understanding of how OAth2 work is fine ?

(2) As far as I know after step 6 (diagram) no further request to authorization server. Then,anyone(intruder) know the token witch given by auth server can communicate to the web API and obtain unauthorized access.how does is not possible.
(I know that token not alter by intruder since then web api new that but without altering it still intruder can communicate to web api)

I know I have miss something please kindly show me where I have missed ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take security measures to protect your token from being stolen. This is no different than preventing session-id from being stolen in session based authentication.

Anyone with access to a valid token is by definition an authenticated user, no matter how the token was retrieved.

Whether your web API communicates with the authentication system directly is not relevant.

Comment: I have small sight on that, once intruder sent message to web Api,It knows where it coming from (different IP address) but token give you different source address (token embedded that) so then web api know it is coming from intruder ?Is that the way Oauth 2 work ?

Comment: That would be fine if you can assume your consumer's IP will not change during the authenticated session. If you have mobile consumer that changes network multiple times, do they have to re-auth every time?

Comment: I think even in mobile device IP the source address that request initiate will not be change otherwise how wep api made there response to the destination ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Let's say I'm a mobile client. I authenticate as I walk outside and my phone does a couple request. This is fine. Then I enter a building and my phone connects to the building's wifi. My phone does more requests, this time with a different IP but still the same token. How would you tell that I am not an intruder, other than asking me to re-authenticate?

Comment: yes agree, but I mean there should be way to recognize your device (may not be the IP) by web api without call to auth server other wise each and every request go to oauth server and then it terribly slow down the connection think about chat application

Comment: And that is exactly the point of token, to identify the entity (a device or user) creating the request. The token must be sent to the API server with every single request. The API server only has to validate that the token is valid (signed, not expired, etc.) and it has enough information to do the verification on its own, without having to contact the auth server on each request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158800/discussion-between-prageeth-and-hendrik-poernama).